# How to remove the fade out effect in this preloader?

Tags: jquery, preloader

I tried to remove the `.fadeOut("slow")`, but the page won't load.

What is the proper way to remove the fade out effect of page on this preloader code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// makes sure the whole site is loaded
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    // will first fade out the loading animation
    jQuery("#status").fadeOut("slow");
    // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
    jQuery("#preloader").delay(5).fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
<style>
#preloader  {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
}
#status  {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url("images/loader.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
</style>
<div id="preloader">Loading... Please Wait.</div>
<div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your JS code to the following should probably do the job

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
      // will first fade out the loading animation
      jQuery("#status").hide();
      // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
      jQuery("#preloader").hide();
})
```

But it's better to just remove the `div` tag with the `id` "preloader". This will remove the whole preloader elements a a whole and it should not show at all.

Comment: what I mean to say is that the fade out effect.. but the preloader.gif removed... in that code. thanks for the reply.